# How to get rid of base 10 multiplier in pgfplots axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm making a graph in tikzpicture using the code below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} %must come before tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width = \textwidth, height = 0.4\textheight, ylabel=\Large{$Y$}, xlabel=\Large{$X$}, xtick={0,2500,5000,7500,10000},  xticklabels={$a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$}, name = border]
\addplot[color=blue, smooth, ultra thick, domain=0:10000] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since a, b, c, d, and e are variable names, it doesn't make sense to have the "*10^4" appear below the x-axis, as it does in the image below.  [image: Graph]

How can I get rid of the multiplier?

Comment: Add `scaled x ticks=false` in your options list for the `axis` environment. By the way, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.